# SDL, change the cursor?

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I'm using the SDL library, but what I'm trying to load a `*.bmp` file and display it as my new cursor, instead of the black and white cursor.

I think, that I most check the position of the mouse and draw the `SDL_Surface` at that position in a loop,

My code so far:

```
//Declare SDL_Surface pointers

SDL_Surface *cursor;
SDL_Surface *image;

SDL_ShowCursor( SDL_DISABLE ); //Standard cursor must be turned off

image = SDL_LoadBMP("mouse.bmp"); //Load my cursor

cursor = SDL_DisplayFormat(image); //Set

//Set the color as transparent
SDL_SetColorKey(cursor,SDL_SRCCOLORKEY|SDL_RLEACCEL,SDL_MapRGB(cursor->format,0x0,0x0,0x0));
```

Comment: see [link](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Displaying_a_Bitmap) but remember **"provide me with code"** is not a great way to ask a question if you expect someone to provide an answer!

Comment: best way to say thanks is to upvote and accept. See [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). Welcome to SO BTW!

Comment: I whant to, but it says " Vote Up reguires 15 reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Create and set a new SDL_Cursor should work.

```
SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load(filename);
SDL_Cursor *cursor = SDL_CreateColorCursor(surface);
SDL_SetCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: The question looks very old, does your solution come from a new feature or new versions of SDL? If yes please mention that. If it has always worked then it's great.